# Can we observe a more recent space?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, spacetime, speed-of-light, observers

The space we are viewing now is their distant past as their light has only reached our eye or telescope after travelling a long distance at the speed of light. However, for lights that are still on the way to the earth, is it possible that we could view them on earth so that we could view a more recent space? For example, the Alpha Centauri we are viewing on earth now is already 4 years in the past. Suppose we observe the light 2 light years away from Alpha Centauri, could we see it 2 years earlier?

Comment: It's gonna take you at least 2 years to get there, it'd still take 4 years to see the light that's getting emitted from it right now

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. According to all known physics, the speed of light is an absolute upper limit to how fast information can travel, so if we look $n$ light years away we see at most events $n$ years ago. Clearly, we cannot see the light en route to Earth before it actually gets to Earth, assuming we are talking about light that is travelling the shortest distance.

There are a couple of caveats and loopholes:

- What is "the present"---that is, what is the set of events happening at the same time as "now"---is reference-frame dependent. Similarly, counting "how many years ago" an event happened depends on the reference frame. For an observer on Earth travelling at $0.99 c$ towards Alpha Centauri, the star would appear to be around half a light-year away. So, from their perspective, they would see it half-year in the past. However, they would see exactly the same events as we see. In other words, all observers in the same location are bound to see the same past, but "how many years ago" that past is depends on the reference frame.
- The above considerations hold in Minkowski spacetime, which is a good approximation for our galaxy. In more general spacetimes, it is still true that the past light cone gives the absolute bound to what is observable, but the definition of "the present" might be even more arbitrary (as there isn't necessarily a natural way to associate a space-like foliation to an individual observer).
- In principle, we would be able to observe the more recent past of Alpha Centaury if a wormhole connected the two regions. A wormhole can be thought of as a "shortcut" through spacetime, so that Alpha Centaury could be only a short distance away when travelling through the wormhole (although it would still be 4 light years away when travelling outside). This would not break the absolute speed limit of information, because light passing through the wormhole would still be bound by $c$. However, since the distance through the wormhole would be much shorter, light could get to us faster than through ordinary space, so we would be able to observe the recent past. Note that wormholes are highly speculative and there is no indication that they are physically possible.
- Another way to "cheat" the limit is if the far-away events were completely determined by a source in the common past, to which we have access. Say that, 2 years ago, a transmitting station half-way between us and Alpha Centaury broadcasted a movie to the two locations. If the movie is playing now both on Alpha Centaury and here, we would effectively be looking at present events happening there. A little less far-fetched consideration is that, given our knowledge of astrophysics and available data, we can make predictions about the evolution of distant objects, which in a sense is a partial way to "see" into the future, or into the more recent past of distant objects.